# How to Export this to fbx Unreal Engine 4

Tags: particles, export, smoke-simulation, unreal-engine, .fbx

[image]Hello guys, i'm very new in blender so can you help me please, i have no idea how to export this to unreal, because I still can't understand how the nodes system works,and what exactly this mesh is.

I created a skull, and want it to move in my game with smoke behind it, so i add a quick smoke and its absolutely works in Blender, but I don't know how to put it in FBX and should I create smoke in Unreal?

Is there a better and easier way ? In the end I want this skull  to move so it will make smoke behind.

Please if you can't give me an answer, a simple advise can be good too :)

Comment: FBX only exports geometry, UVs, some animation properties like rigging, and very basic material properties. Smoke simulations, particles, physics and other specifics of Blender can't be exported, through FBX nor most other formats for that matter. Bottom line is you should be able to export your skull, but everything else you have been wasting your time. unfortunately. It should have been made in game engine, not Blender

Comment: Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos could you add an addendum to that post with your comment thanks. Making that the new master for dupes.

Comment: Just did, feel free to make any corrections you feel necessary. Thanks